# valgrind `--track-fds=yes` without fds 0,1,2

Tags: valgrind

I'm running valgrind with following setup:
`valgrind --tool=memcheck --tool=callgrind --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes --error-exitcode=1 CMD`. Especially,`--track-fds=yes` work as desired, but every run fails due to fds 0,1,2 which are supposed to be open. However, I don't want to drop `--track-fds`, as it certainly gives meaningful information. So, is there a valgrind option / method to track fds excluding 0,1,2?

```
==5872== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
==5872== Open file descriptor 2:
==5872==    <inherited from parent>
==5872== 
==5872== Open file descriptor 1:
==5872==    <inherited from parent>
==5872== 
==5872== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/0
==5872==    <inherited from parent>
==5872== 
==5872== 
==5872== Events    : Ir
==5872== Collected : 3081079256
==5872== 
==5872== I   refs:      3,081,079,256
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. Typically you can ignore these but if you really want to be fastidious:

> fclose( stdin );
>   fclose( stdout );
>   fclose( stderr );

Answer (score 2):

Here's the outupt of the newer versions of valgrind (mine is 3.17) with `--track-fds=yes`:

```
==874818== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open (3 std) at exit.
```

However, if you run valgrind with `--quiet`, it would ignore these 3 std FDs and only notify you about the "real" FDs leak:

```
$ valgrind --quiet --track-fds=yes ./hello_world
hello world!
```

```
$ valgrind --quiet --track-fds=yes ./hello_world_leak
hello world!
==880505== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 4 open (3 std) at exit.
==880505== Open file descriptor 3: /tmp/vg-test/main.cpp
==880505==    at 0x4B968DB: open (open64.c:48)
==880505==    by 0x109249: main (in /tmp/vg-test/hello_world_leak)
==880505==
```